# Difference between FlurryAgent.logEvent and FlurryAgent.onEvent

Tags: java, android, flurry

What is the difference between `FlurryAgent.logEvent` and `FlurryAgent.onEvent`?

I could not find any documentation on these.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

onEvent is deprecated and you should use logEvent in its place.  logEvent also introduced two new overridden methods to allow you to track timed events (not available for onEvent):

- logEvent(String eventId, boolean timed)
- logEvent(String eventId, Map parameters, boolean timed)

Start Edit

To end a timed event use:

- endTimedEvent(String eventId)

End Edit

We will be improving our documentation in the near future so that it is easier to find the answers to these types of questions. Thanks for choosing Flurry.

R,

Anthony

Comment: Thank you very much! I had been using logEvent so this is great

Comment: This is preposterous. The documentation tells you to use onEvent, and when I asked Flurry why my events aren't getting through, I didn't get any response! I will try this method, hope it works better..

Comment: what is difference between timed event and non-timed event ?

Answer (score 1):

here is a link to latest flurry documentation

http://support.flurry.com/sdkdocs/android/classcom_1_1flurry_1_1android_1_1_flurry_agent.html

Answer (score -4):

I used Flurry to track the events. You have to first create an account on the Flurry website and register your project name. Then if you want to track a button and how many times that button was pressed, you go to the Flurry site and you can see it there.

There are three types:

1. Google Analytics
2. Flurry
3. Omniture

Omniture is fast because it is a paid service, and the other two are very slow (it may take them 15 hours to show you your results).

Comment: My question was on the difference of these two methods in Flurry