# Flurry "Event" Add

Tags: android, flurry, flurry-analytics

I know how to `start` and `end` `Sessions in flurry`
I am also able to successfully see them in my `Analytics` section.

What I want to implement now is events for user clicks/views.

I have a media player which plays a file. I want to see how many users have played the file till end. `How add such events inside a session for a user?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize a FlurryAgent after `onCreate()` using:

```
FlurryAgent.init(YourClass.this, "YOUR_API_KEY");
```

Start / End your sessions using: (This will come in your activity class)

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(YourClass.this, "YOUR_API_KEY");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(YourClass.this);
}
```

Now add this line where ever you want to log the event:

```
FlurryAgent.logEvent("Your_event_name");
```

To log events with some parameters, use:

```
HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
myMap.put("key", "value");
FlurryAgent.logEvent("even_name", myMap);
```

Hope this will help somebody.

**NOTE:** If you come across the two terms `FlurryAgent.logEvent` and `FlurryAgent.onEvent`, use `.logEvent`

`.onEvent` is deprecated. Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644781/difference-between-flurryagent-logevent-and-flurryagent-onevent)

Comment: Note: It takes time to reflect on flurry website. I was able to see my event log after `one hour`